# How to save a dictionary (the key to an object) in a file then read it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

i want to save dictionary on file

```
public class TermDocs
{
    public string term { get; set; }
    public int documentid { get; set; }
}
static void Writetermdoc(Dictionary<TermDocs, float> dictionary, string file)
{
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(file))
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            // Put count.
            writer.Write(dictionary.Count);
            // Write pairs.
            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                writer.Write(pair.Key);//error : can not convert from TermDocs to bool
                writer.Write(pair.Value);
            }
        }
}
```

**The best way to write a dictionary that is the key to an object (and how to read it)**

Comment: Is using XML or JSON an option? Those are usually the quickest, most reliable way. You should avoid trying to write such a thing yourself.

Comment: @Christopher I have over a 240k data

Comment: 240 Kilo Byte? I still remember when we had storage Mediums we only could put 1.5 times that on. You know Floppy Disks. | Sorry, but with mere Kilobytes of data you will not shock anyone anymore. That is chump change in the age of *Terrabyte* Disks. It is somewhat justified to be worried about XML bloating up that size - but exactly that is what the JSON alternative is there for. | You should at least use something like CSV for storing this data. Just throwing it down unstructured will backfire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error causes because you are using `BinaryWriter`. Use `StreamWriter` instead

```
public static void Writetermdoc(Dictionary<TermDocs, float> dictionary, string file)
{
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
   {
       // Write pairs.
       foreach (var pair in dictionary)
       {
          writer.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}", pair.Key.documentid, pair.Key.term, pair.Value);
       }
    }
}
```

And to read this file as dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<TermDocs, float> ReadFile(string file)
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    Dictionary<TermDocs, float> dictionary = new Dictionary<TermDocs, float>();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var spl = line.Split('|');
            dictionary.Add(new TermDocs { documentid = Convert.ToInt32(spl[0]), term = spl[1] }, float.Parse(spl[2]));
        }
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: StreamWriter  is work But I can't read from the file and save it to the dictionary

Comment: For that, you can use a splitter, in this case a '|' symbol. And then while reading the file, split and parse the string as you desire. See updated answer for both functions.